# How to title a research paper of a problem which can have two solutions?

Tags: publications

I have been working on a problem which, after a research turn out to have two solutions. One of the solutions is realistic while the other is just a proposed and abstract model.

So for example:

The problem P and two solutions S1(more realistic) and S2(abstract idea).

How can I title the paper?

Comment: I think this is unanswerable, as we don't have any idea what P or S are. Apart from that, I can only think of "Two solutions for P".

Comment: Or you could say "On P"

Comment: I voted to have this question remain opened. I think this question is answerable and on-topic for the site.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible (you have worked on each solution perfectly and each can be published separately), you can publish two papers each include one solution. I mean, you can publish solutions separately if (and only if) each of your solutions are perfectly developed and publishable.

However, if you have derived two separate solutions to a problem, it is not that much difficult to find a title for your paper. Here is one possible title which comes to my mind:

> Solution of problem P by means of two separate methods, S1 and S2

But, if you think the second solution is only an abstract and it is not developed enough to be mentioned in the title, you would better not to mention the second abstract idea in the title of your publication.

Comment: +1.  A "proposed and abstract model" without supporting evidence would not normally be a publishable result.  The paper will stand or fall based on the realistic solution S1, and that is what should go in the title.  The abstract idea S2 can be discussed later in the paper.